# How to Find the List with the Highest Sum of Factorial of its Numbers While Returning Results to Mod M

Tags: algorithm, sum, max, factorial, modulo

Given different lists of numbers, say;

```
list1 --> [2,4,2]
list2 --> [3,5]
list3 --> [4,4,4,4,4,4],
list4 --> [5,5]
list5 --> [6]
```

Find the sum of the factorial of the numbers in each list.
Return the maximum of the sums. Take the sum to Mod M since they can be very large.

For example, in the above lists, the sums for each list, taken M=10^9 + 7, are

```
list1 --> (2!+4!+2!)%M = (2+24+2)%M = 26
list2 --> (3!+5!)%M =  (6+120)%M = 126
list3 --> (4!+4!+4!+4!+4!+4!)%M = (24+24+24+24+24+24)%M = 144
list4 --> (5!+5!)%M = (120+120)%M = 240
list5 --> (6!)%M = 720
```

As can be seen from the above calculation, `list5` is the required list.

My problem is that when items in each list become large, factorial becomes too large pretty fast that the Mod starts taking effects. After Mod takes effect, I would not be able to find the max number since, for example, `1000000008 % M = 1, but 10 % M = 10`.
How do I efficiently find the list that actually gets the max sum?

**Constraints**

```
--> Size of each list is between 1(inclusive) and N(exclusive)
--> Each list contain numbers between 2(inclusive) and N(exclusive)
--> N is between 2(inclusive) and 10^6 (exclusive)
```

Comment: You can simplify the lists before you calculate the factorials. For example, your list [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] is equivalent to [5, 4], because 4! + 4! + 4! + 4! + 4! = 5 · 4! = 5!. So you can sort the list and convert (n +1) consecutive n's to a single (n + 1). After you've done that the factorial of an element cannot be exceeded by sums of smaller elements and the maximum list is the one with the highest count of the highest number in it. If that's a tie, look at the second highest number and so on.

Comment: @MOehm What would be the time complexity of this approach?

Comment: @Wilson I believe that is incorrect.  `mod 10**9 + 7` we have `12 < 13` but `13! < 12!`.

Comment: @Wilson Sorting the a list of `n` integers is `O(n)` with radix sort. Then, you'll want to "chunk" the list: ie `[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3]` becomes `[{count = 3, val = 0}, {count = 1, val = 1}, {count = 1, val = 2}, {count = 2, val = 3}]`. Chunking is again a linear operation. Then, you can efficiently compute the "bubbled-up" version of the list in `O(n)`. So the algorithm will be linear.

Comment: Is there a constraint on N?

Comment: @btilly That is the challenge I was faced with. I could not know the list that gives the biggest sum after taking the `mod`. The question is to identify the list that has the biggest sum of the factorial of its elements

Comment: @Dave I'm sorry I missed that part. Yes! I just updated it. `2<= N < 10**6`

Answer (score 3):

Find the max element, and among these the one with the max count, across all the arrays. Say this is p, repeated r times.

So this array's sum is at least r * p!.

Now, say some other array has a max element of q, and length m. So it's max possible factorial sum is m * q!. What does it take for this other array to possibly have a greater sum? I.e. for it to be worth checking?

If q = p then all we need is m > r for this to be worth checking.

If q = p-1 then we need m * (p-1)! > r * p * (p-1)! so m > r * p.

If q = p-2 then we need m * (p-2)! > r * p * (p-1) * (p-2)! so m > r * p * (p-1)

etc... if q = p-k, then we need m > r * p! / (p-k)!

Whether this is helpful depends on the values in the arrays. E.g. if a single array has a max value of N repeated once, and the next highest value in any array is N-1 or lower then the array with N has to be (or be tied with) the max sum array (because it would take N (N-1)'s to equal N!).

This helps trim down the arrays to check. Unless the max element across all arrays is very small relative to N, this likely narrows you down to a very small set of (max value, max value repetition) values across the survivors. E.g. if p > sqrt(N) then survivors can have a max value no smaller than p-1.

E.g., if N is 100 and the largest value across all lists is 11. Say this is in a list of just one element: [11]. Well, 11! = 39,916,800. Since 100 * 9! is just 36,288,000, we can discard anything with a max element < 10.

We can keep using this idea recurively to find the single highest-value list. Say we're down to two max values: p and p-1. For all the lists which have a max value of p, change their count of ps to zero and for each p gotten rid of, give then p (p-1)s. Next, find the surviving list with the lowest count of (p-1s), and remove the count from all surviving lists. Then repeat the process.

For very small values relative to N we'll be getting more than 2 possible max values. You could either extend this to 3+, or probably just calculate the factorial sums of the survivors directly since all values will be small.

---- Here's an O(num_lists * N) version ----

Say there are L lists.

```
1. Sort each list in O(N) using bucket sort, total is O(L * N).
2. Find the max element across lists, use repetition to break ties. 
3. Say this is p, repeated r times.
4. For each list (including this one): call remove(p, r, list)
5. Repeat for the new max element.

def remove(p, r, list):
    while r > 0 and list.has(p):
        list.remove(p)
        r -= 1
    if r > 0:
        list.remove((p-1) * r * p)
```

The remove method can stop early if a list gets to a situation where no solution is possible (as in the top section of this answer).

This is O(L * N) in total. Each time we call remove, we either remove one of at most N elements, or reduce what we're removing by 1 of at most N elements, so it can be called at most O(2N) times per list before exhausting the list.

---- Ruby code ----

```
def find_max_fsum(lists, n)
  sorted_lists = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [0] * (n+1) }
  
  lists.each_with_index do |list, i|
    list.each do |elt|
      sorted_lists[i][elt] += 1
    end
  end

  max_val = n + 1
  
  while max_val > 1 do
    max_val -= 1
    max_val_reps = 0
    sorted_lists.values.each do |sorted_list|
      max_val_reps = [max_val_reps, sorted_list[max_val]].max
    end
    if max_val_reps > 0
      sorted_lists.each do |i, sorted_list|
        success = remove(max_val, max_val_reps, sorted_list)
        if !success
          sorted_lists.delete(i)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  sorted_lists.keys.each do |i|
    print "max_fsum list: #{lists[i].to_s}\n"
  end
end

def remove(max_val, max_val_reps, sorted_list)
  if max_val_reps <= sorted_list[max_val]
    sorted_list[max_val] -= max_val_reps
    return true
  end
  if (max_val_reps > sorted_list[max_val]) && max_val > 1 
    max_val_reps -= sorted_list[max_val]
    sorted_list[max_val] = 0
    return remove(max_val - 1, max_val_reps * max_val, sorted_list)
  end
  
  return false
end

find_max_fsum([[2,4,2], [3,5], [6,3,3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4,4,4], [5,5], [6, 4]], 6)
max_fsum list: [6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

find_max_fsum([[2,4,2], [3,5], [6,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4,4,4], [5,5], [6, 4]], 6)
max_fsum list: [6, 4]
```

Comment: This idea is good. So at worst case, which is highly unlikely to happen, we would have to discard one element after a check, up to N(exclusive) checks , making it O(N^2). Right?

Answer (score 0):

Every positive integer has a unique "base factorial" representation.  That representation looks like: `a_1 * 1! + a_2 + 2! + a_3 * 3! + ...` with every `a_n <= n`.  This is like a base 10 factorial, but the base increases as you move down the list.

And if you have a factorial representation that isn't in canonical form, you can fix that by starting with 1, 2, 3 and so on, for each one taking `a_n mod (n+1)` as the remainder, and adjusting the next term up.  This is no different than taking something like `25 * 1 + 3 * 10 + 40 * 100` and figuring out that it is `5 * 1 + 5 * 10 + 4 * 1000` so in base 10 it is `4055`.

From your lists you can easily produce a factorial representation, then canonicalize it.  The one with the biggest canonical representation is your answer.

Here is your example to show how it works:

```
list1 --> [2,4,2]
    2 * 2! + 1 * 4!
list2 --> [3,5]
    1 * 3! + 1 * 5!
list3 --> [4,4,4,4,4,4]
    6 * 4! = 1 * 4! + 1 * 5! (This is the first one we had to canonicalize.)
list4 --> [5,5]
    2 * 5!
list5 --> [6]
    6!
```

Now you just sort the canonical representations and find that `list5` is largest, then `list4`, then `list3`, then `list2` then `list1`.

Comment: Finding the canonical form of say `2 * 2! + 1 * 4!` would involve evaluating `2!` and `4!`. Right? Then as the numbers grow, we would need to apply the `mod` to avoid overflow. Right?

Comment: @Wilson No.  All you need to do is work with the coefficients.  Which is why you're able to figure out which one is the largest before having to do any operations with `mod`.  It is much easier to deal with an array of 1000 numbers in the range 1..1000 than to deal directly with 1000!.